# Two query functions in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a Google Sheet query that is pulling data from four other sources.

=QUERY({'1ST A'!A4:BF;'1ST B'!A4:BF;'1ST C'!A4:BF;'1ST D'!A4:BF},"select * where Col1 <>''")

It works well.  I am trying to add an additional query that enables the data to be sorted in the master spreadsheet according to a value in the specific column.  I am trying to add something like this...
=query(A4:BF,"select * order by N asc")

How do I combine the two criteria and am I writing the command correctly?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY({'1ST A'!A4:BF; '1ST B'!A4:BF; '1ST C'!A4:BF; '1ST D'!A4:BF},
 "where Col1 <>'' order by Col14 asc")
```